# Null values When try to post values to Rest webservice using PHP

Tags: php, .net, web-services, rest

When I try to post values to .net REST web service using post method.It will hit the service but the values are not getting posted.
I am using IIS server and here is my PHP code. If I use get method then values are getting post but not with POST.

```
function curl_post_call($url,$data){

    $headers = array(
            'Accept:application/json',
            'Content-Type:application/json',
    );  
    $handle = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($handle,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($handle,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);

    curl_setopt($handle,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($handle,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,false);
    curl_setopt($handle,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
    curl_setopt($handle,CURLOPT_POST,true);
    curl_setopt($handle,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);

    $response = curl_exec($handle);
    //print_r($response);
    $code = curl_getinfo($handle,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    print_r($code);
    return $response;
}


$url = 'http://LHBLREGL003/PayMentRESTService/PayMentService.svc/SaveCVAuditTrail';
$dataArray['ChartID'] = 'chart';
$dataArray['OldValue'] = 'ol';
$data = json_encode($dataArray);
$result = curl_post_call($url,$data);
print_r($result);
```

SERVER Method written in .net Here is the code

```
public int SaveCVAuditTrail(List<CVAuditTrailBLDTO> lstCVAuditTrail)
        {
            int result = 1;

            return result;
        }
```

Any suggestions please ?

Comment: Does the server accept POST method for this URL?

Comment: It would be useful to see the server method.

Comment: updated server method